# EXCEL VBA - Custom Formatting Not Overriding Cell Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to override two columns to mask data from 1111-1111 to ****-*111 for example. Trying to mask ids. I Wrote:

```
 Sub Mask_Account()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fee Letter Formatted")

Sh.Range("B1:B200").NumberFormat = "XXXX-X###"

Sh.Range("D1:D200").NumberFormat = "****-*###"

End Sub
```

But it is not modifying the data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NumberFormat does not change the data, it only masks the data.  If you want to change the data you will need to iterate and use `Format()` to change the number to a text string in the format you put in.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner I might be confused here, because masking was what I was aiming for. Is the way that I am trying to do this equivalent to changing the data? Would I need to make a loop to go through each row?

Comment: masking does not change the data.  It puts a mask on it.  Just like Halloween does not change a bunch of kids into actual witches and vampires.  It covers them to LOOK a certain way, but the base is the same as it was before being covered.  To actually change the data you will need to loop each row and change the data using Format() which takes a number input and returns a string output.  Format() require a one at a time loop.

Comment: Haha thank you. So I am trying to mask the data, but it is not applying the mask on the columns. I thought that the numberformat would do this. Is there a better way that I am missing? Sorry if I am being dense here.

Comment: Your data is text, not numbers. The formatting options for text are basically limited to adding more text or repeating everything that's there.